# how to acces a variable (function) inside a meteor package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a meteor package installed in my Meteor app

```
/packages/mypackage/some_code.js
```

inside is a function:

```
function myFunction(){
    ...
}
```

i would like to call this function from another file inside my metoer app. Both codes are running on serverside.

```
/imports/api/myapi.js
```

How can i access myFunction from myapi.js ?

UPDATE:

After lots of try and error my export looks like this:

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.getResponses = function (){
    return responses;
}
```

and import:

```
import { getResponses } from 'meteor/user:mypackage/myfile.js' ;
```

Comment: Updated my answer - perhaps it is your syntax? Could you update your question with your import/export code?

Comment: _With your new update_: are you calling `export getResponses` anywhere after you define the function? The way you have it now your function is still simply local to the file it is defined in.

Comment: Looks like you were able to figure it out! What were you missing?

Comment: Yes, the .js file inside the package had to be added also(see in question). import the package only was not enough.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic is covered by the [Meteor Guide on Exporting](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#exporting). In that guide:

> While some packages exist just to provide side effects to the app, most packages provide a reusable bit of code that can be used by the consumer with import. To export a symbol from your package, simply use the ES2015 export syntax in your mainModule:

```
// in my-package.js:
export const myName = 'my-package';
```

> Now users of your package can import the symbol with:

```
import { myName } from 'meteor/username:my-package';
```

This works for internal packages found at the `/package` directory as well. Just make sure you have the `ecmascript` core package, and that you are exporting/importing your objects correctly. You will also need to add the name of the package in `.meteor/packages` through `meteor add <package>` or by entering it in manually.

**Edit** - some elaboration on import/export syntax - hopefully this will help you debug the `undefined` issues!

From [MDN's guide on import/export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export):

There are two types of exports, *named* and *default*.

Named exports:

```
export { myFunction }; // exports a function declared earlier
export const foo = Math.sqrt(2); // exports a constant
```

Default exports: (only one per script)

```
export default function() {} // or 'export default class {}'
// there is no semi-colon here
```

Named exports allow exporting multiple values per script, while exporting a default allows one per script, or a fallback.

For example, to import from multiple named exports, you would write:

```
import { myFunction, foo } from 'some-module.js';
```

Whereas importing a default value looks like:

```
import defs from 'definitions.js';
```

Comment: Sounds like this is focused for creating packages which i can then add by `meteor add package` Also i am getting ` SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word ` at the export statement (on meteor i have the ecmascript packagae installed).

Comment: It works the same way for locally stored packages under the `/package` directory. Meteor will look there first using packages listed in the `.meteor/packages` file. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also - does your package depend on ecmascript? Could you post your updated code in the question?

Comment: It's actiually this package https://github.com/steffow/meteor-accounts-saml and the file which i am editing is saml_server.js because i need the response from the idp. But yes i include it not by `meteor add`i have it locally inside the package directory.

Comment: so until now i have just added the line ' export const myName = 'my-package'' in line 5 inside the saml_server.js

Comment: You should be able to import that within a server-only file in your app code

Comment: Tried both named exports and default export but none of them seem to work... always end up with undefined (see Update in Question)